# What should I do if I would like to pass a single mutable object into multiple parameters of a function?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutability

I've written a program in Rust that plays music using stepper motors, and now I'd like to add some fake objects so that I can do automated testing. However, I don't know a good way to define those fake objects in such a way that my program can actually use them.

You can [run my code on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a9a9538ebdd766b3c36f18a416e3b1b).

#### The part that works

The program's main loop uses two trait objects. One object implements a trait called `Timer`, which represents a timer that can be used to make things happen at regular intervals. The other object implements a trait called `Motor`, and represents the stepper motor itself. The definitions of those traits are on [my Rust Playground post](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a9a9538ebdd766b3c36f18a416e3b1b).

The main loop simply waits 500 microseconds, pulls the "step" pin HIGH, waits another 500 microseconds, pulls the "step" pin LOW, and repeats for a total of 1,000 cycles. This causes the motor to step 1,000 times a second for one second.

```
fn spin<T: Timer, M: Motor>(timer: &mut T, motor: &mut M) {
    timer.reset();
    for _ in 0..1000 {
        timer.wait_microseconds(500);
        motor.set_step_high();
        timer.wait_microseconds(500);
        motor.set_step_low();
    }
}
```

So far, everything works just great. I have (in my real code, not the Rust Playground post) a working implementation of `Timer`, and a working implementation of `Motor`, and the `spin` function makes the motor spin, and it sounds beautiful.

#### The problematic part

I want to be able to do automated testing, so I've written a "fake" object which implements `Motor` and `Timer` in a way that's useful for testing. The type itself is just a struct:

```
/// A mock timer and motor which simply tracks the amount of simulated time that
/// the motor driver has its "step" pin pulled HIGH.
struct DummyTimerMotor {
    is_on: bool,
    time_high: u64,
}
```

The implementations of `set_step_high` and `set_step_low` just set `is_on` to `true` and `false` (respectively), and the implementation of `wait_microseconds` just checks whether or not `is_on` is `true` and adds the given amount of time to `time_high` if so. Those implementations are in [my Rust Playground post](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a9a9538ebdd766b3c36f18a416e3b1b).

Naively, I would expect to be able to pass a `DummyTimerMotor` object as both parameters of `spin`, and then look at `time_high` afterward, and see that it has a value of 500000. However, that is, of course, not allowed:

```
fn main() {
    let mut dummy: DummyTimerMotor = DummyTimerMotor {
        is_on: false, time_high: 0
    };
    
    spin(&mut dummy, &mut dummy); // Oops, not allowed!
    
    print!("The 'step' pin was HIGH for {} microseconds", dummy.time_high);
}
```

This gives an error message: "cannot borrow `dummy` as mutable more than once at a time."

I know exactly why I'm getting that error message, and it makes sense. What's a good way to get the behavior I'm trying to get?

I only have one reasonable idea: change `spin` so that instead of taking an object which implements `Timer`, and another object which implements `Motor`, it takes a single object which implements both `Timer` and `Motor`. However, that seems inelegant to me (as a Rust newbie). Conceptually, a timer is one thing and a motor is another thing; having `spin` take a single object which is both a timer and a motor is quite unintuitive. It doesn't seem like I should change the way that `spin` is implemented merely to accommodate the details of how the timer and motor are implemented.

---

#### Full code listing

In case the Rust Playground ever goes down, below is the entire program that I have there, along with the entire error output.

```rust
/// A timer which can be used to make things happen at regular intervals.
trait Timer {
    /// Set the timer's reference time to the current time.
    fn reset(&mut self);
    /// Advance the timer's reference time by the given number of microseconds,
    /// then wait until the reference time.
    fn wait_microseconds(&mut self, duration: u64);
}

/// The interface to a stepper motor driver.
trait Motor {
    /// Pull the "step" pin HIGH, thereby asking the motor driver to move the
    /// motor by one step.
    fn set_step_high(&mut self);
    /// Pull the "step" pin LOW, in preparation for pulling it HIGH again.
    fn set_step_low(&mut self);
}

fn spin<T: Timer, M: Motor>(timer: &mut T, motor: &mut M) {
    timer.reset();
    for _ in 0..1000 {
        timer.wait_microseconds(500);
        motor.set_step_high();
        timer.wait_microseconds(500);
        motor.set_step_low();
    }
}

/// A mock timer and motor which simply tracks the amount of simulated time that
/// the motor driver has its "step" pin pulled HIGH.
struct DummyTimerMotor {
    is_on: bool,
    time_high: u64,
}

impl Timer for DummyTimerMotor {
    fn reset(&mut self) { }
    
    fn wait_microseconds(&mut self, duration: u64) {
        if self.is_on {
            self.time_high += duration;
        }
    }
}

impl Motor for DummyTimerMotor {
    fn set_step_high(&mut self) {
        self.is_on = true;
    }
    
    fn set_step_low(&mut self) {
        self.is_on = false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut dummy: DummyTimerMotor = DummyTimerMotor {
        is_on: false, time_high: 0
    };
    
    spin(&mut dummy, &mut dummy); // Oops, not allowed!
    
    print!("The 'step' pin was HIGH for {} microseconds", dummy.time_high);
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `dummy` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:61:22
   |
61 |     spin(&mut dummy, &mut dummy); // Oops, not allowed!
   |     ---- ----------  ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |    |
   |     |    first mutable borrow occurs here
   |     first borrow later used by call
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why don't you implement a `DummyTimer` and `DummyMotor` ? Why have you merged them in one ?>

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html

Comment: @SvetlinZarev My implementation of `Timer` looks at the `is_on` variable in order to know whether to add the given amount of time to `time_high` or not, and my implementation of `Motor` sets the `is_on` variable. I don't see an obvious way to implement them separately, given that they interact in this way.

Comment: I don't want to write totally separate, non-interacting versions of `DummyTimer` and `DummyMotor` either. With the real-life implementations, calling `timer.wait_microseconds(500);` and then calling `motor.set_step_high();` has a different effect than calling `motor.set_step_high();` and then calling `timer.wait_microseconds(500);`. I'd like to be able to write testing code that's also capable of reacting to those two things differently.

Comment: that sounds like your DummyMotor is not a valid stand-in then?

Comment: "timer is one thing and a motor is another thing". Then design wise, one object shouldn't be a `Timer` and a `Motor` at the same time, or atleast not used in two places behaving like both of them in two different places (I mean function arguments).

Comment: Very unsafe and probably suffers from UB: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a596635fca04081697112e67050159c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a distinct `DummyTimer` and `DummyMotor` who share state through a `Rc<RefCell<State>>`:

```
struct State {
    is_on: bool,
    time_high: u64,
}

struct DummyTimer {
    state: Rc<RefCell<State>>,
}

impl Timer for DummyTimer {
    fn reset(&mut self) { }
    
    fn wait_microseconds(&mut self, duration: u64) {
        let mut t = self.state.borrow_mut();
        if t.is_on {
            t.time_high += duration;
        }
    }
}

struct DummyMotor {
    state: Rc<RefCell<State>>,
}

impl Motor for DummyMotor {
    fn set_step_high(&mut self) {
        self.state.borrow_mut().is_on = true;
    }
    
    fn set_step_low(&mut self) {
        self.state.borrow_mut().is_on = false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let state = Rc::new (RefCell::new (State { is_on: false, time_high: 0, }));
    let mut motor = DummyMotor { state: Rc::clone (&state), };
    let mut timer = DummyTimer { state: Rc::clone (&state), };

    spin(&mut timer, &mut motor); // Now it's allowed
    
    print!("The 'step' pin was HIGH for {} microseconds", state.borrow().time_high);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00be276bd613b741774b83d96281a9fe)

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reasons you cannot have two mutable references to your `DummyTimerMotor`,
but you can try some `unsafe` hackery to achieve something similar. This approach
is inspired by [`slice::split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut)
and [`tokio::io::split`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/io/fn.split.html)

Basically you can create two proxy objects, one implementing `Timer` and one
implementing `Motor`:

```rust
impl DummyTimerMotor {
    pub fn split<'a>(&'a mut self) -> (impl Timer + 'a, impl Motor + 'a) {
        let ptr_is_on = &mut self.is_on as *mut bool;
        let ptr_time_high = &mut self.time_high as *mut u64;

        (
            TimerHalf::<()>::new(ptr_is_on, ptr_time_high),
            MotorHalf::<()>::new(ptr_is_on),
        )
    }
}

struct TimerHalf<'a, T: 'a> { // the dummy parameters are needed for the PhantomData
    is_on: *mut bool, // or *const bool instead
    time_high: *mut u64,
    // we need the phantom data in order to prevent someone from creating another 
    // borrow on the DummyTimerMotor and to track where it's safe to use this 
    // TimerHalf instance
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T> TimerHalf<'a, T> {
    fn new(is_on: *mut bool, time_high: *mut u64) -> TimerHalf<'a, ()> {
        TimerHalf {
            time_high,
            is_on,
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Timer for TimerHalf<'a, T> {
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        //
    }

    fn wait_microseconds(&mut self, duration: u64) {
        unsafe {
            if *self.is_on { // how safe is this ? 
                *self.time_high += duration;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MotorHalf<'a, T: 'a> { // the dummy parameters are needed for the PhantomData
    is_on: *mut bool,
    // we need the phantom data in order to prevent someone from creating another 
    // borrow on the DummyTimerMotor and to track where it's safe to use this 
    // MotorHalf instance
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T> MotorHalf<'a, T> {
    fn new(is_on: *mut bool) -> MotorHalf<'a, ()> {
        MotorHalf {
            is_on,
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'l, T> Motor for MotorHalf<'l, T> {
    fn set_step_high(&mut self) {
        unsafe { *self.is_on = true }
    }

    fn set_step_low(&mut self) {
        unsafe { *self.is_on = false }
    }
}
```

The rules around raw pointers are very vague and I could not find any authoritative
document on whether you are allowed to dereference 2 mutable raw pointers to the
same data. All I could find was that it's not allowe to dereference a mut raw pointer
for as long as there is a mut reference, because that would violate the aliasing rules.

Well, in that case there are no references at all, so I *guess* that this is fine.
I've run some experiments with MIRI and it didn't report any violations, but I'm
not sure if that is any guarantee of UB-free behavior.

Then you can use it like that ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb060b071becf17d5c7462a48ea6e4aa)):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut dummy: DummyTimerMotor = DummyTimerMotor {
        is_on: false,
        time_high: 0,
    };

    let (mut t, mut m) = dummy.split();

    spin(&mut t, &mut m);


    // let (mut t, mut m) = dummy.split(); - not allowed - already borrowed (that's fine!)
    // unless you drop the timer/motor halves :)

    drop(t); 
    drop(m);

    
    print!(
        "The 'step' pin was HIGH for {} microseconds",
        dummy.time_high
    );
}
```

Relevant resources:

- [Splitting borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html)

PS: @Jmb's solution **IS** better for your use-case, but as I've spent quite a lot of time researching this, I've decided to post it anyway in hopes of someone shedding some light on the unsafe aspects of my approach